# Entity framework 6 - Reusing Select queries

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using .net and Entity Framework 6

I have a table `Activities` in SQL Server, which has a `ExerciseType` column

I am trying to count the total number of rows for each exercise type.

```
//dbCtx is of type System.Data.Entity.DbContext 
int nbType1 = dbCtx.Activities.Count(a => a.Exercise == "TYPE1");
int nbType2 = dbCtx.Activities.Count(a => a.Exercise == "TYPE2");
int nbType3 = dbCtx.Activities.Count(a => a.Exercise == "TYPE3");
int nbType4 = dbCtx.Activities.Count(a => a.Exercise == "TYPE4");
```

These are the queries corresponding to the previous code:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (N'TYPE1' = [Extent1].[ExerciseType])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (N'TYPE2' = [Extent1].[ExerciseType])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (N'TYPE3' = [Extent1].[ExerciseType])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Activities] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (N'TYPE4' = [Extent1].[ExerciseType])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

The queries are slow.

As the query is almost identical for each call to EF.

Is there a possibility to improve performance by caching the query ?

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: Hi Alex, around 800'000

Comment: So a second to pull into memory? Easy. (and yes, I do the same for a similar size data set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in a single query and extract the values on the returned dataset.

So in SQL you would do:

```
SELECT ExerciseType, COUNT(ExerciseType) as ETCount 
FROM Activities 
GROUP BY ExerciseType
```

So by taking off the where clause and adding grouping, you return counts grouped by the exercise type.

In EF, it should look something like this:

```
var results = dbCtx.Activities 
                   .GroupBy(a => a.Exercise)
                   .Select(a => new { ExerciseType = a.Key, ETCount = a.Count() });
```

The output would be something like:

```
Exercise | ETCount
------------------
TYPE1    | 3
TYPE2    | 9
TYPE3    | 6
TYPE4    | 12
```

Comment: thanks, to make it work, I just had to change the code to

    

    var results = dbCtx.Activities
                                      .GroupBy(a => a.Exercise)
                                      .Select(a => new { ExerciseType = a.Key, ETCount = a.Count() })

Comment: @stephone updated answer to include your code snippet.